# How can I get the current parent sample "Sampler results" properties values in a child JSR223 Postprocessor test element?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jsr223

In JMeter I have a JSR223 Sampler with a child JSR223 Postprocessor.
I want to know if it's possible to get the parent sample "Sampler results" properties inside the JSR223 Postprocessor so that based on the a result comparison I could take some action in the Postprocessor like write something in the jmeter log file for example.

I am most interested in the value of the property called "Load time", but others could be useful as well.

Here is an example screenshot from the View Results Tree Listener of the properties and values which I would like to access:
[image]

Also, I am curious to know if these properties can be individually set (overridden) with some custom desired value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `prev` shorthand which provides access to [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) functions and fields, for example:

- `prev.getTime()` - will give you the "Load Time"
- `prev.getThreadName()` - will give you the "Thread Name"
- etc.

`log` shorthand will print the given String to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) so you could do something like:

```
 log.info('Sampler load time: ' + prev.getTime())
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)